# Agent connection in GIS space is not working in AnyLogic

Tags: gis, anylogic, agent

I was trying to make distance based agent(people) connection. It was working in a continuous space (see attached). But not working in GIS space. In GIS space we don't have option to select network type under "space and network type". So, I have created a function to do that. That function is also working perfectly in continuous space but not in GIS space. Anybody can explain why it is happening or is there any way to do it GIS space.

My GIS space has 190 regions and random number of people located randomly (uploaded from database) in each region.
[image: continuous space][image: GIS space]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define networks and connections yourself, the option you used so far is only a little helper, but the actual capabilities are much larger, also in GIS:

Just use the custom "[Agent Link](https://file:///C:/Program%20Files/AnyLogic%208.8%20Professional/plugins/com.anylogic.ui_8.8.1.202210270952/resources/help/en/anylogic/agentbased/link.html)" object and its properties. It is designed to connect agents in any space, also GIS.

Check the help and example models to learn all about it, it is worth it :)
[image]

Comment: I used "Link to agents" following exactly your blog example (https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2017/10/21/anylogic-agent-links-a-hidden-gem-for-your-connections). Only difference is the GIS space.

Comment: I found in GIS space it is not working. Surprisingly, when I deleted the GIS map and drawn a rectangular node and put people in the node, I found the connection is working perfectly. May I request you to create a mini example with GIS map and use the Link to agents and see if it is working for you.

Comment: You are right, it does not work. The reason is that the GIS map does not support 2D lines, it is an entirely different environment. So you need to animate those connections yourself using programmatic GIS routes, see https://anylogic.help/markup/create-gis-network-by-code.html#creating-a-gis-network

Comment: thank you so much, Sir. It seems lot of works. Let me work on it and will get back to you if I will have any questions.